# PXImageUploader extend image into frame

Tags: acumatica

I would like to remove the white borders
[image]

```
<px:PXImageUploader MagnifyDefault="False" ViewOnly="False" FlexRatio="False" ShowComment="False" Height="150px" Width="420px" ID="imgUploader" runat="server" DataField="ImageUrl" DataMember="ItemSettings" AllowUpload="true" SuppressLabel="False" ></px:PXImageUploader>
```

Is there a property?

Comment: You can try adding a CSS like this to the site `.imgDiv {
    margin: 0px !important;
}`